# delete_post hook in Wordpress not working

Tags: wordpress, debugging, hook, action

```
add_action( 'delete_post', 'test_function' );
function test_function(){
    echo "Hello!";
}
```

The "Hello!" isn't showing up when I delete a post (It is a custom post-type, but that shouldn't matter right?). How do I debug this?

**EDIT:** I can't put that code in any front-end files like header.php or index.php because I won't be able to view the output when I delete a post from the back-end. What's the best way to tackle this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try doing the following to see if you are reaching your filter. I tested this here with 3.2.1 and it works fine for me.

```
function test_function(){
    die('deleted post');
}
```

this action will not run until you delete the post from the trash.
If you want it to run when you move it to the trash the action is 'trash_post'.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much. Also, what is the action when I decide to 'un-trash' a post? (Is there a page that has a comprehensive list of every action? The Wordpress docs don't seem to have anything like that).

Comment: The action for that is 'untrash_post' - there is a page on the codex that has a list of the available actions - http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Comment: However, the best way to find the action and when they run is to look into core. these actions are in /wp-includes/post.php

Comment: Seems like the hook name for trashing a post is now 'wp_trash_post'